# Where can I find logs of diplomacy agreements?

Tags: civilization-5

I can't find a screen to see a log of diplomacy agreements, those like when we settle a city close to another empire and they complain about it, and we agree to not do so anymore.

These agreements last for some amount of turns and when finished we're notified that now we can again settle close to them. But where can I see the active ones and how many turns left?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but afaik you can see all current treaties in additional information -> diplomacy overview (it's a bit tricky to read but you should get it pretty fast).

The additional information button is the smaller one with the scroll inside on top right of the screen (4th button from right to left if I recall correctly, my memory is not what it used to be).

Comment: Are you talking about the Trade History tab of the Diplomacy screen? If so, that tab doesn't include these non-trade agreements.